# Replace specific values in a XML file

Tags: xml, rebol, rebol3

There is a snippet from a XML file like this:

```
"...<id>90,123</id>...<id>190</id>...<id>123,90</id>...
<id>123,90,123</id>...<id>901</id>"
```

I want to replace all the number 90 with another number, e.g. 100. Using `replace/all` will ruin numbers like 190 and 901. `rejoin replace/all parse str "<>," "91" "147"` will eliminate the `<>,`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your input is:

```
st1: "...<id>90,123</id>...<id>190</id>...<id>123,90</id>...<id>123,90,123</id>...<id>901</id>"
```

Then try this:

```
delimiter: charset ">,<"
s: copy ""
rule: [
    some [
        copy del1 delimiter "90"
        copy del2 delimiter (
            append s rejoin [del1 "100" del2]
        )
    |
        copy c skip (
            print "other char" append s c
        )   
    ]
]
parse st1 rule
print s
```

Will output:

```
...<id>100,123</id>...<id>190</id>...<id>123,100</id>...<id>123,100,123</id>...<id>901</id>
```

This helped me find a Red bug as well :)

Comment: Great! It solves my problem perfectly. Thanks a lot! Very happy to see that you found a Red bug by it. :)